# Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<Bundle__c> at line 71 column 119

Tags: apex, soql, controller, list

Not sure what i need to modify in this code to get rid from this error

```
public void retrieveBundleInfo() {
    bundlewithProduct = [SELECT Id, (select Id, Name, Product__c, Product__r.ProductCode, Product__r.Description, Quantity__c from Product_Quantities__r) FROM Bundle__c WHERE Id =: QBP.Bundle__c];
    try {
        this.ListPrice = string.ValueOf([SELECT Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice FROM PriceBookEntry where Product2Id =: bundlewithProduct.Product_Quantities__r.get(0).Product__c]);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        this.ListPrice = '';
    }        
}
```

Comment: What is `bundlewithProduct` type is it a `List<Bundle__c>`?

Comment: @RCS Yes, it is `List<Bundle__c>`

Comment: Is the error on this line `this.ListPrice = string.ValueOf([SELECT Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice FROM PriceBookEntry where Product2Id =: bundlewithProduct.Product_Quantities__r.get(0).Product__c]);`

Comment: Yes. is where clause correct ?

Comment: Where clause is not correct you need to change the where clause

Comment: could you please tell me what changes need ?

Comment: Please check the below answer, you need to put the list index for which the value you want to access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53121/discussion-between-rcs-and-wanttobeacoder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use below code

Where bundlewithProduct list zero index value is accessed.

```
public void retrieveBundleInfo() {
    bundlewithProduct = [SELECT Id, (select Id, Name, Product__c, Product__r.ProductCode, Product__r.Description, Quantity__c from Product_Quantities__r) FROM Bundle__c WHERE Id =: QBP.Bundle__c];
    try {
        this.ListPrice = string.ValueOf([SELECT Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice FROM PriceBookEntry where Product2Id =: bundlewithProduct[0].Product_Quantities__r.get(0).Product__c]);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        this.ListPrice = '';
    }        
}
```

Comment: If i want to multiple `ListPrice` for each Product then do i need for loop ?

Comment: Yes for sure you'll need a for loop to iterate and store the ListPrice in collection. Create a Map<Prodcut, ListPrice> that stores the Product wise ListPrice.

Comment: Ok. Let me do it that way and let you know :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only one PriceBookEntry for the given product, and you are trying to get the UnitPrice to assign to ListPrice, then you could do this:

```
PriceBookEntry pbe = [SELECT Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice FROM PriceBookEntry where Product2Id =: bundlewithProduct[0].Product_Quantities__r.get(0).Product__c LIMIT 1];
this.ListPrice = string.ValueOf(pbe.UnitPrice);
```

or

```
this.ListPrice = string.ValueOf([SELECT Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice FROM PriceBookEntry where Product2Id =: bundlewithProduct[0].Product_Quantities__r.get(0).Product__c LIMIT 1].UnitPrice);
```